# Multiple answers for a node in Bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a bot using Microsoft bot framework. for the language processing, I use Luis so that I can ask the same question in a different way.  is there a way to respond the same answer in a different way as in below-using bot framework

```
[
    "Hi, How is it going?",
    "Good"
],
[
    "Hi, How is it going?",
    "Fine"
],
[
    "Hi, How is it going?",
    "Okay"
],
[
    "Hi, How is it going?",
    "Great"
],
[
    "Hi, How is it going?",
    "Could be better."
],
[
    "Hi, How is it going?",
    "Not so great."
]
```

I am using Node.js to develop this

Comment: Do you want the multiple answers in LUIS?

Comment: yes I do, by the way I figure it out

Answer (score 0):

it can done passing an array of answers to send methond as in `session.send(["Good","Fine","Okay","Great","Could be better.","Not so great."])`